# There's no option to turn on wifi or bluetooth in my pc

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth

I saw questions related to this. But my problem is different. My desktop PC is 4-5 years old running on windows 10. I recently started using it more often when my laptop started causing problems. I access net through a wired connection. As for bluetooth, I tried adding a bluetooth device in settings, and got this :

[image]

So that means either my drivers aren't updated or my device doesn't support bluetooth. The latter is more likely since I couldn't find any option to turn on my bluetooth. Similarly, I couldn't find any option to turn on my wifi, let alone scanning. Do I need to add a suitable piece of hardware to get the options of wifi and bluetooth? If yes, then what? If no, what can I do about this?

Edit:

[image]

System Model : B85M-D3H
System Version : 10.0.18363 Build 18363
Motherboard by Gigabyte

Comment: If your desktop PC did not come with a Wi-Fi or Bluetooth interface built-in, you will need to purchase one. There are a variety of devices available that do this, USB, PCIe, etc. Choose one that you are most comfortable with installing and is in your price range. Just Google "USB Wi-Fi adapter" or "USB Bluetooth adapter". Some even come as a combo unit where you can get both in one.

Comment: First off, add on the post the **model and version of your laptop** and the **Windows version** ( you can run the cmd **winver** to get it).

Comment: You can use bluetooth adapter that connects through usb ports.

Comment: is WiFi and Bluetooth enabled in the BIOS? If its not it most likely wont even show up in Windows

Comment: Will order a USB adapter.as far as BIOS is concerned, I didn't find any setting for bluetooth in BIOS.

Comment: And i am quite convinced that it did not come with wifi or bluetooth interface built in, thx guys for all the help

Answer (score -1):

issue : ncpa.cpl in windows run or on cmd and check if you can see your adapter there.
If the adapter is there and is disabled, you'll need to activate it(right click, enable).
If you can't find your adapters, it might be a driver issue. To confirm check if the driver is installed for your adapter in windows driver manager.